# Ionic 2- Infinite scroll not calling method on second scroll

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have used `ion-tab` to display a page (`inboxitem`) that contains `ion-list` and uses `ion-infinite-scroll`.

I have following code in `inboxitem.html`

```
<ion-content class="inbox can-swipe-list">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-list-header>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" [selectOptions]="filterOptionSettings" (ngModelChange)="getFilteredList()">
                <ion-option value="{{option.value}}" *ngFor="let option of listInboxFilterOptions; let i=index" [selected]="i==0">{{option.name}}</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-list-header>

        <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let list of inboxList; let j=index">
            <ion-item class="listWithReason" tappable (click)="ViewPopupDetails(j)">
                <h2>
                    <span>{{list.fullname | filterpipes:'manipulatename'}}<br /><small>{{list.leavename}}</small></span>
                    <div> <ion-icon md="md-calendar" ios="md-calendar"></ion-icon> {{list.fromdate}}{{list.todate!=null ? " to ":" " }}{{list.todate}}</div>
                </h2>
                <p *ngIf="list.reason!=''">{{list.reason}}</p>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item-options side="right" *ngIf="list.empphone=='' || list.empphone==null">
                <button ion-button color="grey" class="no-phone">No phone</button>
            </ion-item-options>
        </ion-item-sliding>

         <ion-item class="item-empty-row" *ngIf="!inboxList.length > 0">
            {{noRecordsFound}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-infinite-scroll *ngIf="infiniteLoading" (ionInfinite)="loadInboxList(false)" distance="1%">
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

**PROBLEM**

1. By default 20 records are loaded
2. On scroll it loads 20 more.
3. But on second scroll it only shows spinning animation, but doesn't load any records. That is, in second scroll, it does not call `loadInboxList` method at all. So its clear that its nothing wrong in the `loadInboxList` method because it is not called at all on the second scroll.

***My ionic and cordova versions***

```
Ionic Framework: 3.5.0
Ionic App Scripts: 1.3.9
Angular Core: 4.1.3
Angular Compiler CLI: 4.1.3
Node: 6.10.3
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you call **infiniteScroll.complete();** in your loadInboxList() .

If by any chance you are calling infiniteScroll.enable(false) in your code, this will prevent the scroll to work on any subsequent scrolls until you enable it again.

**EDIT**

now i noticed you are not passing the event in your (ionInfinite) method -

it should look like this:

```
(ionInfinite)="loadInboxList($event)"
```

and in your .ts

```
loadInboxList(infiniteScroll){
     ...your code 
     infiniteScroll.complete()
}
```